# Python - replacing an array via multi-column index and .replace() function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, datetime, indexing

Replace filtered array (a) with another column's same-as-filtered array (b).

````
In[1]import pandas as pd
     import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
     %matplotlib inline
     import seaborn as sns
     sns.set(font_scale=1.5)
     import numpy as np
     import datetime
     from pylab import rcParams
     rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 20, 10```
````

-

```
#definition of a
In[2] a = df.fldLastUpdatedDate[df.index[df.fldScheduleCreatedDt.notnull() & 
          df.fldLastUpdatedDate.isnull()]]
In[3] a
Out[3]917   NaT
      932   NaT
      933   NaT
      934   NaT
      938   NaT
             ..
     69932  NaT
      Name: fldLastUpdatedDate, Length: 20802, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

-

```
#definition of b
In[4] b = df.combined[df.index[df.fldScheduleCreatedDt.notnull() & 
          df.fldLastUpdatedDate.isnull()]]
In[5] b
Out[5]917   2011-08-12 09:00:00
      932   2011-08-09 09:00:00
      933   2011-08-09 10:15:00
      934   2011-08-04 13:00:00
      938   2011-08-02 12:30:00
                    ..
     69932  2018-11-02 15:00:00
      Name: combined, Length: 20802, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

-

```
#replace a with b
In[5] df.fldLastUpdatedDate = df.fldLastUpdatedDate.replace(a,b)
```

-

```
#check a
In[6] a
Out[6]917   NaT
      932   NaT
      933   NaT
      934   NaT
      938   NaT
             ..
      69932 NaT
      Name: fldLastUpdatedDate, Length: 20802, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

No change (and no errors). Joy.

Questions sounding solutions I've considered:

(1) Is there a debugging tool I could use to walk me through what's going on here?

(2) Am I using `.replace()` within it's SOP's parameters?

(3) Are there any other non-loop based solutions which would fit the criteria of solving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand this question correctly you have one `DataFrame` that you are applying two filters on (`a` and `b`). You want to replace values for `a` in `df.fldLastUpdatedDate` that match with indexes in `b`.

This is fairly straight forward if you use `loc`.

Let's begin by making some dummy data:

```
x = list(range(0,10))
for i in range(0,10):
    x.append(None)
np.random.shuffle(x)
y = list(range(0,20))
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'x': x, 'y': y})
```

Next step we create our boolean mask:

```
x_is_null = df['x'].isnull()
```

We then apply our mask and update 'x' with values from another series with matching index:

```
df.loc[x_is_null, 'x'] = df['y']
```

---

In your case I would rewrite the code as such:

**Step 1**: Create our boolean mask for `a`:

```
a = df.fldScheduleCreatedDt.notnull() & df.fldLastUpdatedDate.isnull()
```

**Step 2:** Apply our boolean mask and replace with data from column called `combined` using `loc`:

```
df.loc[a, 'fldLastUpdatedDate'] = df['combined']
```

Comment: Understood perfectly. Thank you very much!